# Remove Spaces in columns value in sql table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to remove a space from table columns value  in sql.

my column name is `ParagraphStyle` and  my string is like

```
'first_page
'
```

I used this

```
select * 
from customizeFunction_test_from_frontend 
where (LTRIM(RTRIM(ParagraphStyle)) = 'first_page')
```

but I got no result.

Suggest me to get a solution

Comment: how about using `trim`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634558.aspx ?

Comment: to remove spaces in particular column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LTRIM and RTRIM only remove spaces. 
There is no built in function to trim all whitespace so you would have to write your own code/function for that.

I found one here:http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/10/sql-server-2008-enhenced-trim-function-remove-trailing-spaces-leading-spaces-white-space-tabs-carriage-returns-line-feeds/

... I'm not sure they want the code copied here, hence the link.